# Angular Material Date Picker

Tags: angular, material-design

I cant seem to gleam any direction from the docs here

https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker

Does anyone know how I can get the value of the input after the date has changed ?

It emits an event emitter but I dont know how to hook into it

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe to the [`selectedChanged`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.ts#L117) output, which emits `date` like

```
this.selectedChanged.emit(date);
```

So you need something like:

```
this.picker.selectedChanged.subscribe((date) => { ... });
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TXXpCgbTEjPeJmJSXWwt?p=preview)